# Minimal value of $\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq 2014}a_ia_j$ where $a_i=\pm1$

Tags: summation, contest-math

Let $a_i \in \{-1,1\}$ for all $i=1,2,3,...,2014$ and $$M=\sum^{}_{1\leq i<j\leq 2014}a_{i}a_{j}.$$ Find the least possible positive value of $M$.

Came across this question in a Math Olympiad and I'm not sure how to even start, the answer given is 51.

Comment: Try some small cases first, rather than the case with $2014$.  What does that tell you?  Provide your effort in the small case in your question.

Comment: This only depends on the number of $1$'s and $-1$'s in the sequence - you could phrase it in one variable.

Comment: @steamyroot yes, its positive sorry.

Comment: It's been quite a few years since I was a mathlete, but there doesn't seem to be enough of a constraint on *j* for this question to be non-trivial. Just make a2014 = -1, all the others equal to 1, and choose *j* for each *i* such that they all even out except for one, and your answer is 1. What am I missing in the problem statement?

Comment: @DCShannon The notation is short for a sum over all values of i and j, so you can't choose j. Another way of writing it would be $\displaystyle  \sum_{i=1}^{1024}\sum_{j=i+1}^{1024} a_i a_j$

Comment: @phihag That would be it then, thanks. That's not actually all values of i and j, though, if j is initialized as i+1 for the given i.

Comment: Not all values as in $\mathbb{R}$ or the like, but all values in $\mathbb{N}$ that match the condition under the sum sign ($1 \le i \lt j \le 2014)$ .

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Hint: $\displaystyle \left(\sum_{i=1}^{2014}a_i\right)^2=\sum_{i=1}^{2014}a_i\sum_{j=1}^{2014}a_j = \sum_{i=1}^{2014}a_i^2+2\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq 2014}a_i a_j.$

Comment: So that will give $M=\sum^{}_{1\leq i<j\leq 2014}a_{i}a_{j}=\frac{1}{2} [(\sum^{2014}_{i=1}a_{i})^{2}-2014]$ since $a_i$ can only be 1 or -1 the term just becomes 2014. But how do i deal with the other term?

Comment: Think about what value $\sum a_i$ can take, given the limited possibilities of $a_i$.

Comment: @SteamyRoot's comment above is relevant here: I can easily enough come up with a sequence such that $\sum_i a_i=0$ and get $M=-1007$. So some additional constraint is needed to get 51 as the result.

Comment: Since $a_i$ is either 1 or -1, the difference between choosing one as 1 or -1 would be 2. So it has to be an even number and getting $0.5(46^2-2014)=51$ ah thank you!

Comment: @ItsImpulse : what is $46$ ? I don't get it

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
\mbox{Since}\quad
\sum_{1\ <\ i\ <\ j\ <\ 2014}a_{i}a_{j} =
\half\bracks{\pars{\sum_{i = 1}^{2014}a_{i}}^{2} -  2014}\quad\mbox{with}\quad
a_{i} = \pm 1
$$

the problem is reduced to find the minimum value of
$\ds{\pars{\sum_{i = 1}^{2014}a_{i}}^{2}}$ such that

$$
\pars{\sum_{i = 1}^{2014}a_{i}}^{2} > 2014\quad\imp\quad
\verts{\sum_{i = 1}^{2014}a_{i}} > \root{2014} \approx 44.8876
$$

Let $n_{+}$ the number of $a_{i}$'s that have the values $+1$. Then,

\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 1}^{2014}a_{i} & =
n_{+}\times 1 + \pars{2014 - n_{+}}\times\pars{-1} = 2\pars{n_{+} - 1007}
\quad\mbox{which is a $\color{#f00}{even}$ number}
\end{align}

So, we are forced to choose
$\ds{\verts{\sum_{i = 1}^{2014}a_{i}} = \color{#f00}{46}}$ because
$\ds{\color{#00f}{45}}$ is an $\color{#00f}{odd}$ number. Then

$$
\half\pars{46^{2} - 2014} = \color{#f00}{51}
$$